# String to Date conversion (everything seems good but fail)

Tags: java, date, date-conversion

How to parse this string?

"Mon Jul 02 13:49:16 CEST 2012"

```
String Date = "Mon Jul 02 13:11:38 CEST 2012";
DateFormat formatter;
Date convertedDate= new Date();
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
try {
     convertedDate = (Date) formatter.parse(Date);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(ItemRecTestCases.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Dont work..."`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date:`"

Comment: you shouldn't call your string variable Date

Comment: @dystroy its a bit lame that you can

Comment: Your code works fine with Java 7.

Comment: @assylias That's because your computer is configured for an `en` or `us` locale.

Comment: @assylias Yes. "Argh". They should really deprecate this constructor...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the locale :

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Or else "Mon" cannot be parsed as "monday".

Comment: Oh, that is so awkward... but true, thank you... Not only Mon, but Jul and month names also cant convert!!!!

Comment: Ok course. But I know I make frequently this error and each time I scratch my head a few minutes. Allowing a constructor without locale is almost a bug from Sun in my opinion.

Answer (score 6):

The Locale needs to be specified:

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: Perfect answer also, but i will "accept" dystroy because of the description of the problem Mon -> Monday :( Jul -> July because in my country Jul -> Július ( ú!!!(