# How to convert string like "Tue, 06 May 2014 15:27:23 +0000" to Java-Date?

Tags: java, android, string, sqlite, date

I need to convert a string (e.g. "Tue, 06 May 2014 15:27:23 +0000") to java date to store in in a sqllite-database. I used the following code, but it does not work (ParseException):

```
public static Date formatDate(String theDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = formatter.parse(theDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return date;
}
```

Do you have any ideas? Thanks for your help!

Best regards,

Robin

Comment: The format you're using obviously do not correspond to the text you're trying to parse. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for proper formatting.

Comment: you should really read the documentation to understand what you are doing with this format.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String to Date conversion (everything seems good but fail)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293134/string-to-date-conversion-everything-seems-good-but-fail)

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the correct format.

Try:

EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z